# How to plot y-axis bands in Altair charts?

Tags: python, altair

Can Altair plot bands on the y axis, similar to [this Highcharts example](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-plotbands)?

The docs have [an example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/selection_layer_bar_month.html) showing how to draw a line on the y axis, but adapting the example to use `plot_rect` to draw a band instead doesn't quite work:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

weather = data.seattle_weather.url

chart = alt.Chart(weather).encode(
    alt.X("date:T")
)

bars = chart.mark_bar().encode(
    y='precipitation:Q'
)

band = chart.mark_rect().encode(
    y=alt.value(20),
    y2=alt.value(50),
    color=alt.value('firebrick')
)

alt.layer(bars, band)
```

[image: plot_rect with fixed y and y2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem when you give a value with `alt.value` is that you specify the value in pixels starting from the top of the graph : it is not mapped to the data.

In the initial answer, with `mark_rule`, it would'nt create a clean band but a lot of vertical stripes, so here is a way to correctly plot a band.

First solution is to create a brand new data frame for the band, and layer that on top of the bars:

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd
from vega_datasets import data

weather = data('seattle_weather')
band_df = pd.DataFrame([{'x_min': weather.date.min(),
                         'x_max': weather.date.max(),
                         'y_min': 20,
                         'y_max': 50}])

bars = alt.Chart(weather).mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T'),
    y=alt.Y('precipitation:Q', title="Precipitation")
)

band_2 = alt.Chart(band_df).mark_rect(color='firebrick', opacity=0.3).encode(
    x='x_min:T',
    x2='x_max:T',
    y='y_min:Q',
    y2='y_max:Q'
)

alt.layer(bars, band_2)
```

[image]

Second option, if you do not want/cannot create a dataframe, is to use `transform_calculate`, and manually specify `x` and `x2` in the band chart:

```
bars = alt.Chart().mark_bar().encode(
    x=alt.X('date:T', title='Date'),
    y=alt.Y('precipitation:Q', title="Precipitation")
)

band_3 = alt.Chart().mark_rect(color='firebrick', opacity=0.3).encode(
    x='min(date):T',
    x2='max(date):T',
    y='y_min:Q',
    y2='y_max:Q'
).transform_calculate(y_min='20', y_max='50')

alt.layer(bars, band_3, data=data.seattle_weather.url)
```

[image]

**Initial answer**

I would do 2 things to mimic the highchart example you gave. First, use a `transform_calculate` to set `y_min` and `y_max` values. And second, I'll use `mark_rule` so that the band span on the X axis where there are values. (I also added some opacity and changed the order of the layers so that the band is behind the bars.)

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

weather = data.seattle_weather.url

chart = alt.Chart().encode(
    alt.X("date:T")
)

bars = chart.mark_bar().encode(
    y='precipitation:Q'
)

band = chart.mark_rule(color='firebrick',
                       opacity=0.3).encode(
    y=alt.Y('y_min:Q'),
    y2=alt.Y('y_max:Q')
).transform_calculate(y_min="20",
                      y_max="50")


alt.layer(band, bars, data=weather)
```

[image: altair_plot_with_band]

Comment: If you zoom in, the red area consists of lots of vertical lines (one per x value in the data), so that wouldn't work if there were gaps in the data... `mark_rect` on the other hand does work, but appears to be overlaid once for each value, so ends up being solid even with a low opacity value...